# Search Multiple tables Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problems that I'm not sure how best to approach. I have three tables in my database that I need to retrieve data from and display.

**Tables**: `Variety`, `Trial`, `Result`

I have a **form**:

```
<%= simple_form_for :search, url: vpc_search_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :variety_one, collection: @variety, :include_blank => false %>
    <%= f.input :variety_two, collection: @variety, :include_blank => false %>
    <%= f.input :irrigations, collection: @irrigations, as: :check_boxes, :input_html => {:checked => true} %>
    <%= f.input :years, collection: @years, as: :check_boxes, :input_html => {:checked => true} %>
    <%= f.input :regions, collection: @regions, as: :check_boxes, :input_html => {:checked => true} %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

My **Controller**

```
class VpcController < ApplicationController
  def index
    all = Result.select(:variety_id)
    @variety = Variety.where(:variety_id => all).order('variety_name DESC').pluck(:variety_id)
    @years = Result.select('DISTINCT year').pluck(:year)
    @regions = Trial.select('DISTINCT region_id').pluck(:region_id)
    @irrigations = Trial.select('DISTINCT irrigated').pluck(:irrigated)
  end

  def search
    @search = params[:search]
  end
end
```

My **Model**

```
class Vpc < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :varieties
  has_many :results
  has_many :trials
end
```

What I need is once the search form is complete it displays results in a table:

```
Variety One |  Variety Two  | Difference
```

Answer (score 1):

There is little more to be done to achieve what you want. In the search method instead of getting all the params, get the varieties variety_1 and variety_2  params, find then in the database and use the associations to find the results,then compute the difference. Create a view and display the information.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create/update multiple objects in one form, then I suggest you to create pseudo-Model without connection to database, for example:

```
class Node
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :name, :content, :variety, :region, :etc

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  def save
    # here you do save of your data to distinct models
    # for example
    named_model = NamedModel.create! name: name, variety: variety
    details = Details.create! region: region, etc: etc
    content_holder = ContentHolder.create! content: content, named_id: named_model.id, details_id: details.id
  end

end
```

And use it like normal active model:

```
<%= form_for @node do |f| %>
  <% f.text_field :name %>
  <% f.text_area :content %>
  <% f.text_field :variety %>
  <% f.text_field :region %>
  <% f.text_area :etc %>
  <% f.submit %>
<% end %>
```